# Convert E-Mail Address to SamAccountName

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I have a csv like this:

```
Group;User
TestGroup1;test1@domain.com
TestGroup2;test2@domain.com
```

Now I want to add the Group to the User. I cant add them by the mail address so I have to get the SamAccountName. This is what I've come up with:

```
Import-module ActiveDirectory

foreach ($item in (Import-CSV users.csv -delimiter ";"))
{
    $userMail = $item.("User")
    $userSAM = Get-ADUser -Filter {mail -eq $userMail} -Properties SamAccountName
    Write-Host $item.("Group") $userSAM
}
```

But the Variable "UserSAM" stays emtpy.

Comment: Have you made sure that $userMail is not empty?

Comment: Try `$item.User` instead of `$item.("User")`.

Comment: @JeffZeitlin They evaluate the same, but it's the worst syntax I've ever seen someone use (I think)

Comment: Use `Get-ADUser -Filter $SID -Properties *` and make sure you're accessing the correct member (i.e., `mail` may be the wrong property name).

Comment: `$item.("User")` only "works" by accident; it's not semantically correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should return just the usernames which you can use to add the user to the group.

```
Import-Module ActiveDirectory
foreach ($item in (Import-CSV users.csv -Delimiter ";")) {
      $userMail = $item.User
      $userSAM = Get-ADUser -Filter {mail -eq $userMail} | Select-Object -ExpandProperty SamAccountName
      Write-Host $item.Group $UserSAM
}
```

If this returns what you need just add this line into the end of the loop:

```
    Add-ADGroupMember -Identity $item.Group -Members $UserSAM
```